# How to initialize and populate an immutable map that holds an immutable map as one of the values of a key in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, immutability

I've been trying to solve this issue where I have to initialize and populate the structure at the same time as indicated below code segment.

```
private static Map<String, Map<String, String[]>> Errors = ImmutableMap.<String, ImmutableMap<String, String[]>>builder()
```

This is what I tried, but it just does not work.

```
private static ImmutableMap<String, ImmutableMap<String, String[]>> Errors = ImmutableMap.<String, ImmutableMap<String, String[]>>builder()
            .put(PppoeAgentStatTypes.RECEIVED.getCounterType(), ImmutableMap.put(PppoeAgentCounters.AC_SYSTEM_ERROR.getCounterType(), new String[]{PppoeAgentCounters.PADS.getCounterType(), PppoeAgentCounters.PADO.getCounterType()}),
                    ImmutableMap.of(PppoeAgentCounters.SERVICE_NAME_ERROR.getCounterType(), new String[]{PppoeAgentCounters.PADS.getCounterType(), PppoeAgentCounters.PADO.getCounterType()})).build();
```

I have tried populated using `of` or just using `put` but couldn't get a successful result. I either got error saying ImmutableMap is abstract and can't be instantiated or different syntax errors. How can I initialize and populate the structure above?

Comment: Create a normal mutable map, initialize it, then call `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` to make it immutable.

Comment: I'm assuming this is `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap`?

Comment: What error do you get?  This looks like you just need `ImmutableMap.of`, not `put`; you never call `put` on an `ImmutableMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Map.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V)), which

> Returns an unmodifiable map

for both the outer map and the map values.

For example:

```
private static Map<String, ImmutableMap<String, String[]>> Errors = Map.of(
  PppoeAgentStatTypes.RECEIVED.getCounterType(), Map.of(PppoeAgentCounters.AC_SYSTEM_ERROR.getCounterType(), new String[]{PppoeAgentCounters.PADS.getCounterType(), PppoeAgentCounters.PADO.getCounterType()}),
  // more keys and values
);
```